# Is 60 minutes enough layover time at Los Angeles International Airport?

Tags: layovers, short-connections, lax

I am flying in to LAX on American Airlines and have a 60 min layover before I fly out with American Airlines (same ticket).

Will this be enough time?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. While it *should* be enough time, assuming your flights are domestic, operated by American or American Eagle, and on a single booking, it would be helpful to know which terminals you will be arriving and departing from and what time of day it would be.

Comment: never been to LAX though generally if its on the same ticket then the airline expects it to be enough and will accomodate you if something goes wrong.

Comment: @theotherone The trick is that the standardized Minimum Connection Times do not take into account things like airport construction, people with mobility problems, or delays due to irregular operations, so it always pays to do a little research.

Comment: While not AA, I believe it's timely to point out that [Delta is moving from T5 to T2/3](http://news.delta.com/delta-relocate-upgrade-operations-lax-through-19b-plan) at LAX soon, likely at or before May 2017 which will (obviously) immediately make any Delta-at-LAX answers outdated.

Comment: We would be arriving in LAX at 8:41am and departing at 9:45am, and yes my flight is domestic

Answer (score 5):

Talking based out of experience.

American Airlines operates from Terminal-4 (http://www.lawa.org/LAXAirlines.aspx). They also operate from Terminal 6, gates 60-63 as mentioned on the LAX web site.

*Domestic:*

1) If your connecting AA flight is from the same terminal as that of your arrival, 60 minutes is good enough.

2) If your connecting AA flight is from another terminal i.e. either T4 to T6 or T6 to T4, you should still be good as the commute between T4 and T6 is small and the airport provides shuttle services too.

http://www.lawa.org/uploadedFiles/LAX/pdf/LAX%20Airline%20Location%20Map.pdf

*International:*

I have done international transits with connections of 60-75 minutes. However, immigration and security for international travel might take much longer and hence I would recommend a longer transit time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I walked from Terminal 6 to terminal 4 about 3 hours ago.  Took no more than 10 minutes (maybe a few minutes more depending on how fast you walk, and which gates were involved)

Answer (score 0):

As it is a single ticket, it should be OK. The airlines know how long of a connection is necessary at each of their hubs and create itineraries that meet those anticipated connection needs.

That said however, you don't have any leeway time to stop and grab food or drink.  And if your incoming flight is delayed, you could be doing the LAX dash.

Comment: My experience is that 'Airlines know'  is generally not a good good assumption.  There are too many localized factors like construction as someone correctly pointed out to the alerts issued that very day which airline cannot possibly take into account.

Comment: @mohsin - you can find exceptions and situations that dont folow the rule of thumb.  If you are going to consider every every possible exception

Answer (score -1):

My experience of Lax is that of an efficient airport.  Within the same terminal you don't have anything to worry about and most likely that would be the case. Even across terminals since you will already have your boarding pass and your luggage will already be checked in, this time should be sufficient.

Once you are in a TSA queue which is blind to the time when your flight closes, it all depends on your luck as well as on the ability of other passengers to follow simple instructions like not having liquids in their bags. 
I have missed tight connections like this a few times but airline always accommodates on the next flight so it has never been a major inconvenience.

Comment: I believe only if the airport you boarded from offers US pre-clearance.